# Parse a JSON data efficiently using ObjectMapper iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

Hi I have a `JSON` that is in the given format

```
"exclusions": [
    [
      {
        "facility_id": "1",
        "options_id": "4"
      },
      {
        "facility_id": "2",
        "options_id": "6"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "facility_id": "1",
        "options_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "facility_id": "3",
        "options_id": "12"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "facility_id": "2",
        "options_id": "7"
      },
      {
        "facility_id": "3",
        "options_id": "12"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

I am using `Object Mapper` library to parse the `JSON` but from my knowledge , I feel it is missing a key, as each object under the key `exclusions` is an array, 
Is there anyway I can parse this using ObjectMapper

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried? What do you want it to look like when you're done parsing it?

Comment: Don't use ObjectMapper now `Codable` is available

Answer (score 1):

And why not `Codable`

```
class Root:Codable {
  let exclusions:[[InnerItem]]
}
class InnerItem:Codable {
   let facilityId:String
   let optionsId:String
  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case facilityId = "facility_id"
     case optionsId = "options_id"
  }
}
```

//

```
do {
     let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:jsonData)
     print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

BTW your json needs a surrounding `{}`